# Database design about Customer, Industry and SubIndustry

Tags: database, database-design, relational-database

I am a new one in database design and learning how to design a good database. I am a little confused about the following scenario.

For now, I have an Excel flat table with customer information as shown as following.

[image]

One customer comes from one company and only belongs to Industry and Subindustry. I also have a pre-defined `Industry` and `SubIndustry` tables, the value recorded in customer table can only be taken from those two tables.

[image]

I want to separate those tables into three parts, they are `customer_table`, `Industry_table` and `Subindustry_table`respectively. Obviously, `Industry_table` and `Subindustry_table` has the one-to-many relationship which is one Industry has many subindustries. Just like this:

[image]

But I don't know how to deal with the relationship among customer, industry and subindustry. For example, If I want to add one new customer into the system, I can select his industry and subindustry from `industry_table` and `subindustry_table` and store them together into the database, If I search one customer, the corresponding industry and subindustry information can also be selected.

My question is how to design this relationship among them.

I design an ER diagram like this, but Obviously, this will lose the connection between customer and subindustry.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since a `SubIndustry` can only be part of 1 industry, adding `SubIndustry_id` in place of `Industry_id` in the `customer` table "Creating a 1-many from `SubIndustry` to `Customer` instead of the 1-many from `Industry` to `customer`" is more efficient imo, since it includes the industry and subindustry